# OpenXml C# can not merge numerous cells

Tags: c#, .net, openxml-sdk

```
 SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
            Row headers = new Row();
            headers.Append(new Cell
            {
                CellValue = new CellValue("Losses"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 2U,
                CellReference = new StringValue("A1")
            });
            headers.Append(new Cell
            {
                CellValue = new CellValue("Target"), DataType = CellValues.String, StyleIndex = 2U,
                CellReference = new StringValue("F1"),
            });
            sheetData.Append(headers);

            // creating headers in one row
            sheetData.Append(CreateHeaderRowForExcel(type));

            byte level = 1;
            foreach (MaterialLossDto obj in data)
            {
                sheetData.Append(AddRowsRecursion(obj, ref level, sheetData));
            }

            //create a MergeCells class to hold each MergeCell
            MergeCells mergeCells = new MergeCells();
            //append a MergeCell to the mergeCells for each set of merged cells
            mergeCells.Append(new MergeCell() {Reference = new StringValue("A1:D1")});
            mergeCells.Append(new MergeCell() {Reference = new StringValue("F1:G1")});
            sheetData.Append(mergeCells);
```

i create workSheet and step by step fill data in row. when i create headers, i want create one long header with merged cells. but it doesn't work for me. all rows are filled and my long header contains only one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is not so obvious. creating merged cells need after all manipulations with WorkSheet. here is all my code

```
   public class ReportLoaderBase<T> : IReportLoader<T> where T : class, IReportDto
    {
        private const string WorksheetPartId = "partId1";
        private protected List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cellsPair;

       
        public string Download(ReportTypeGeneric<T> genericModel, string fileName)
        {
            string outputFilePath = $"{FileServiceHelper.OutputDirectory}\\{fileName}";
            if (!Directory.Exists(FileServiceHelper.OutputDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FileServiceHelper.OutputDirectory);
            CreateExcelFile(genericModel, outputFilePath);
            return outputFilePath;
        }

        private void CreateExcelFile(ReportTypeGeneric<T> model, string outputFilePath)
        {
            using SpreadsheetDocument excelFile =
                SpreadsheetDocument.Create(outputFilePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
            CreatePartsForExcel(excelFile, model);
        }

        private protected virtual void CreatePartsForExcel(SpreadsheetDocument excelFile,
            ReportTypeGeneric<T> model)
        {
            SheetData sheetData = GenerateSheetDataForDetails(model.Elements, model.ElementsType);
            ContinueCreatingPartsForExcel(excelFile, sheetData);
        }

        private protected void ContinueCreatingPartsForExcel(SpreadsheetDocument excelFile, SheetData sheetData)
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = excelFile.AddWorkbookPart();
            GenerateWorkbookPartContent(workbookPart);

            WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rId3");
            GenerateWorkbookStylesPartContentNew(workbookStylesPart);

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>(WorksheetPartId);
            GenerateWorksheetPartContent(worksheetPart, sheetData);
        }

        private protected virtual SheetData GenerateSheetDataForDetails(List<T> data, Type type)
        {
            SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
            // creating headers in one row
            sheetData.Append(CreateHeaderRowForExcel(type));

            foreach (var obj in data)
            {
                // generate values
                Row rows = GenerateRowForChildPartDetail(obj);
                sheetData.Append(rows);
            }

            return sheetData;
        }

        private protected virtual Row CreateHeaderRowForExcel(Type type)
        {
            Row row = new Row();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsListType())
                    continue;
                // 2U for header
                Cell cell = CreateCell(propertyInfo.Name.Replace('_', ' '), 2U);
                row.Append(cell);
            }

            return row;
        }

        private Cell CreateCell(string text)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.StyleIndex = 1U;
            cell.DataType = ResolveCellDataTypeOnValue(text);
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);
            return cell;
        }

        private protected Cell CreateCell(string text, uint styleIndex)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex;
            cell.DataType = ResolveCellDataTypeOnValue(text);
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);
            return cell;
        }

        private EnumValue<CellValues> ResolveCellDataTypeOnValue(string text)
        {
            int intVal;
            double doubleVal;
            if (int.TryParse(text, out intVal) || double.TryParse(text, out doubleVal))
            {
                return CellValues.Number;
            }

            return CellValues.String;
        }

        private protected virtual Row GenerateRowForChildPartDetail(object model)
        {
            Row row = new Row();
            Type type = model.GetType();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsListType())
                    continue;
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(model);
                // 1U for text
                row.Append(CreateCell(value?.ToString() ?? "", 1U));
            }

            return row;
        }

        private void GenerateWorkbookPartContent(WorkbookPart workbookPart)
        {
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet {Name = "Sheet1", SheetId = 1, Id = WorksheetPartId};
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            workbook.Append(sheets);
            workbookPart.Workbook = workbook;
        }

        private void GenerateWorksheetPartContent(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, SheetData sheetData)
        {
            Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet
            {
                MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes
                {
                    Ignorable = "x14ac"
                }
            };
            // configurations
            worksheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r",
                "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            worksheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            worksheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");

            SheetDimension sheetDimension = new SheetDimension {Reference = "A1"};

            SheetViews sheetViews = new SheetViews();

            SheetView sheetView = new SheetView {TabSelected = true, WorkbookViewId = 0U};
            Selection selection = new Selection
            {
                ActiveCell = "A1",
                SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>
                {
                    InnerText = "A1"
                }
            };

            sheetView.Append(selection);

            sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
            SheetFormatProperties sheetFormatProperties = new SheetFormatProperties
            {
                DefaultRowHeight = 15D,
                DyDescent = 0.25D
            };

            PageMargins pageMargins = new PageMargins
            {
                Left = 0.7D,
                Right = 0.7D,
                Top = 0.75D,
                Bottom = 0.75D,
                Header = 0.3D,
                Footer = 0.3D
            };

            worksheet.Append(sheetDimension);
            worksheet.Append(sheetViews);
            worksheet.Append(sheetFormatProperties);
            worksheet.Append(sheetData);
            worksheet.Append(pageMargins);
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;
            MergeCells(worksheetPart);
        }

        private void MergeCells(WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
        {
            if (cellsPair == null)
                return;

            //create a MergeCells class to hold each MergeCell
            MergeCells mergeCells = new MergeCells();
            //append a MergeCell to the mergeCells for each set of merged cells
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in cellsPair)
            {
                mergeCells.Append(new MergeCell() {Reference = new StringValue($"{pair.Key}:{pair.Value}")});
            }

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());
        }

        private void GenerateWorkbookStylesPartContentNew(WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart)
        {
            Stylesheet stylesheet = new Stylesheet(new Fonts(
                    new Font(new FontSize() {Val = 14}, new Color() {Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() {Value = "000000"}},
                        new FontName() {Val = "Times New Roman"}),
                    new Font(new FontSize() {Val = 14}, new Color() {Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() {Value = "000000"}},
                        new FontName() {Val = "Times New Roman"}), new Font(new Bold(), new FontSize() {Val = 11},
                        new Color() {Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() {Value = "000000"}},
                        new FontName() {Val = "Times New Roman"})
                ),
                new Fills(
                    new Fill(
                        new PatternFill()
                        {
                            PatternType = PatternValues.None
                        }),
                    new Fill(
                        new PatternFill()
                        {
                            PatternType = PatternValues.None
                        }),
                    new Fill(
                        new PatternFill(new ForegroundColor()
                        {
                            //  change color
                            Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() {Value = "FFFFAAAA"}
                        })
                        {
                            PatternType = PatternValues.Solid
                        })
                ),
                new Borders(
                    new Border(new LeftBorder(), new RightBorder(), new TopBorder(), new BottomBorder(),
                        new DiagonalBorder()),
                    new Border(new LeftBorder(new Color() {Auto = true}) {Style = BorderStyleValues.Medium},
                        new RightBorder(new Color() {Indexed = (UInt32Value) 64U}) {Style = BorderStyleValues.Medium},
                        new TopBorder(new Color() {Auto = true}) {Style = BorderStyleValues.Medium},
                        new BottomBorder(new Color() {Indexed = (UInt32Value) 64U}) {Style = BorderStyleValues.Medium},
                        new DiagonalBorder())
                ),
                new CellFormats(new CellFormat() {FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, ApplyFont = true},
                    new CellFormat(new Alignment()
                    {
                        Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center,
                        WrapText = true
                    }) {FontId = 1, FillId = 0, BorderId = 1, ApplyFont = true},
                    new CellFormat(new Alignment()
                    {
                        Horizontal = HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center, Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Center,
                        WrapText = true
                    }) {FontId = 2, FillId = 2, BorderId = 1, ApplyFont = true})
            );
            workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;
        }
    }
}
```